# BufferedImage.getGraphics() resulting in memory leak, is there a fix?

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, bufferedimage

I'm having problem with some framework API calling BufferedImage.getGraphics() method and thus causing memory leak. What this method does is that it always calls BufferedImage.createGraphics(). On a windows machine, createGraphics() is  handled by Win32GraphicsEnvironment which keeps a *listeners* list inside its field *displayChanger*. When I call getGraphics on my BufferedImage *someChart*, *someChart*'s SurfaceManager(which retains a reference to *someChart*) is added to the *listeners* map in Win32GraphicsEnvironment, preventing *someChart* to be garbage collected. Nothing afterwards removes *someChart*'s SurfaceManager from the *listeners* map.

In general, the summarized path stopping a BufferedImage from being garbage collected, once getGraphics is called, is as follows:

GC Root -> localGraphicsEnvironment(Win32GraphicsEnvironment)
-> displayChanger(SunDisplayChanger) -> listeners(Map) -> *key*(D3DChachingSurfaceManager) -> bImg(BufferedImage)

I could have changed the framework's code so that after every called to BufferedImage.getGraphics(), I keep a reference to the BufferedImage's SurfaceManager. Then, I get hold of localGraphicsEnvironment, cast it to Win32GraphicsEnvironment, then call removeDisplayChangedListener() using the reference to the BufferedImage's SurfaceManager. But I don't think this is a proper way to solve the problem.

Could someone please help me with this issue? Thanks a lot!

---

MORE DETAILS AND FINDINGS

The component I'm trying to add to my UI is makes calls to BufferedImage.getGraphics() every time it is repainted. As a result, the number of garbage kept by [*displayChanger*](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ND67gFy8cpo/src/share/classes/sun/java2d/SunGraphicsEnvironment.java&q=sungraphicsenvironment&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc)(inside *SunGraphicsEnvironment*) should grow as the component gets repainted.

However, things a behaving weirdly enough:

when I counted my actions on my UI which would surely trigger repaint, then check the number of garbage listeners inside *displayChanger* against my count, they don't match up. (eg. There were 8 listeners before my clicks, and I made 60 clicks. After all, there are only 18 listeners.)

On the other hand, if I turn on the breakpoint, and step into the process of adding things to *displayListeners*, every single click resulted in a new entry in *displayListeners*. And thus, every BufferedImage held by *displayListeners* become garbage.

I considered the possibility of SurfaceManager, which is used as the key for displayListeners, may be shared or reused, yet my experiment ruled out this possibility. I also considered caching and I deliberately prevented caching from happening by making every call to repaint unique. Still, I have no clue how this could happen and how to solve the leak.

Answer (score 7):

After rendering the `BufferedImage`, you should invoke [`dispose()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose%28%29) on the graphics context returned by `createGraphics()`. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658663) and a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486200) of similar methods.

Addendum: This seems like an object leak called [packratting](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/packratting.html); the listener mismatch sounds like an artifact of using the debugger. You might get some ideas from the article [*Plugging memory leaks with soft references*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01246.html), by Brian Goetz.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that dispose() method was called, but it does not release the image because a reference is still held by displayChanger. I even tried to get hold of the image's surface manager and call flush() hoping to destroy the manager. It didn't work.

Comment: @user359202: I wonder about the font cache in `SunGraphicsEnvironment`; I've elaborated above.

Comment: Sounds really close. Could you elaborate more about the font cache in SunGraphicsEnvironment and how this may relate to my problem? There's little information available on this part of java I could find.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call [`flush()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#flush()) when you don't need your image any more.