# Change Color BufferImage

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, actionevent

I want to change the color of my `BufferdImage`. 
When I do it like in this post: [BufferedImage draw white when I say red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843426/bufferedimage-draw-white-when-i-say-red) it works only in my method which constructs my `JFrame` with all the components.

But when I want to use it in an `ActionEvent` in my `Controller` class, it does nothing, but the rest of the `ActionEvent` works, like for example change text in text field.

Methods in the `JPanel` class:

```
public void testImage(){
    System.out.println("Methode suc. called");
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    tempC = Color.GREEN;
    g.setColor(tempC);
    g.fillRect(150, 300, 100, 100);
    tempC = Color.CYAN;
    g.setColor(tempC);
    g.fillOval(0, 0, 100, 100);
    g.dispose();
    if(image == null){System.out.println("Image is null");} 
}

public void clearImage(){
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    tempC = Color.WHITE;
    g.setColor(tempC);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, darstellungsBreite, darstellungsHoehe);
    g.dispose();
}
```

The `ActionListener`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if(arg0.getActionCommand().equals(view.ACTION_CLEAR))
    {
        //Clear Graphics
        view.drawArea.clearImage();
        //view.useClear();
    }
```

Comment: Depending on the rest of your code, you may need to call `repaint()` on the component that displays the image. The image is its own entity, not the pixels on the screen.

Comment: jep, solved the problem! I only had to replace g.dispose with repaint() :)

Comment: It's still good practice to dispose the graphics objects you create (like those obtained with `Image.getGraphics()`). So don't replace it, just add the repaint call.