# How do I get AppContext to release AWT components so they can be garbage collected?

Tags: java, swing, memory-management

My team is working on analyzing our Swing application to make sure everything is being garbage collected when it's no longer being used.  We're running into an odd problem.

We are simply opening a new window (`JFrame`) and closing it.  This frame contains an `EmptyPanel` class (which contains a short message saying there is no data) and a custom `JMeunBar` class.  We don't interact with this at all - just close the window immediately.

Then, we force a garbage collection and do a heap dump.

Upon analysis of the heap dump, the `JMenuBar` isn't being garbage collected.  It's being kept open from the GC Root `sun.awt.AppContext`.

How do we clean this up?  Or is this something we don't have to worry about for some reason?  We want to be diligent making sure our application cleans up after itself, but we don't want to spin our wheels on this either.

`AppContext.mainAppContext` contains a HashMap which contains a `BasicPopupMenuUI.MenuKeyboardHelper` instance.  Inside this is a `ComponentInputMapUIResource.menuInputMap` which has this `JMenuBar` as a component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486136/what-method-in-java-is-used-to-destroy-your-objects/2486200#2486200) there are a number of system resources that must be freed explicitly in the normal course of the JVM's operation. The graphics context's [`dispose()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose%28%29) method is one example; the parent window's [`dispose()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) method is another. In either, the resource may be correctly released, but you may observe the heap before it has been finalized.

It's hard to generalize about what can be safely ignored, but one empirical approach is to exercise the target in a profiler. The first two graphs in this [comparison](https://sites.google.com/site/trashgod/garbageheap) show a small but steady increase in memory consumed by a certain method that is suspected of retaining resources. In contrast, the third chart shows flat memory use with periodic spikes of garbage collection activity. Below is the typical saw-tooth pattern of a visually "busy" program such as this [game](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons). Note that each cycle returns to the baseline.

[image]

Comment: I added an explicit call to `JFrame.dispose()`, and I still get the same results. The only thing I can think at this point is that these resources really don't take a lot of memory, so I shouldn't worry about them.  It's much more important that we clear the hundreds of megabytes of data we load than this stuff, which may get cleared out later once a certain buffer maxes out or something like that.

Comment: That proved true for `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView()`, which is called infrequently in practice. I'd say you're right to focus on the data.