# how to use timer with SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

need an example, how to use timer in SwingWorker ? because it impossible to add an ActionListener to my Timer like that !

```
private Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    }
});
```

Message Error : **The constructor Timer(int, new ActionListener(){}) is undefined**

Comment: `Timer in SwingWorker ?`... AFAIK, you use `javax.swing.Timer` for short tasks, that needs to be done on the EDT (though you can also use java.util.Timer with some `STRINGS attached` on it's proper usage), while you use `SwingWorker` for a long running background task, whose output is something you wanted to convey on the EDT. You don't use them together.

Comment: Here is one wonderful [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11282106/1057230) by @mKorbel. Here is one [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10051684/1057230).

Comment: One more wonderful [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7748847/1057230).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your source, looks like you are importing different **Timer** class. Are your using **`javax.swing.Timer`**. Refer the [API document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) here.

May be you had imported `javax.management.timer.Timer` or `java.util.Timer`

Comment: +1 yes IDEs do mess up the `Swing Timer` imports and `Timer Task` imports