# How to update JTable continously without running out of memory?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a application that reads log messages from syslog, parses it and breaks it down into 4 fields i.e "timestamp", "facility", "severity" and "message".

I display this entire data in a `JTable` (with 4 columns). I also simultaneously write these data to xml files.

The problem is that the current `DefaultTableModel` runs out of memory when we keep adding rows(whenever new log messages arrive). So is there any other table model that can fit my use case.(i.e the `JTable` must display all the log messages to the user without running out of memory).

If at all I try to implement my very own custom table model to update from the xml files when model reaches a certain limit, what are the things I must keep in mind (i.e problems, ideas) when designing such a model.

Note: I cannot use a database

Thanks.

Comment: The question is, how much do you really need to keep in memory?  Can trim off old messages?  I would also seriously consider looking at using something like a single user database system like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) - IMHO

Comment: Actually since its a logger i need all the log messages to displayed to the user.About using a database, will it take too much time to implement them ( i do not know much about them).Could you give any already implemented examples related to this so that i can refer to it?

Comment: You could explore the use of a disk backed collection, but it would require you to implement your own `TableModel`

Comment: disk backed collection are there any that are under free license.(Since what my company is developing is a propertry based IDE tool).Could give some tips to what problems i can face when going ahead such a design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several possibilities:

- [Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) your application to identify possible spurious object allocation or retention, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310284/230513).
- Alter the virtual machine's heap allocation, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15307253/230513).
- Explore a disk based paging scheme suited to your use-case.