# Are there any proper uses for Object#finalize() despite being "should not relied on"?

Tags: java

Since [Object#finalize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize())'s introduction in JDK 1.0, Java introduced 9 more versions.

Yet, despite its clear [shortcomings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450597), it is still available, even in JDK 10.

Oracle itself states in [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html):

> **The finalize() Method**
>
> The Object class provides a callback method, finalize(), that *may* be
>   invoked on an object when it becomes garbage. Object's implementation
>   of finalize() does nothing—you can override finalize() to do cleanup,
>   such as freeing resources.
>
> The finalize() method *may* be called automatically by the system, but
>   when it is called, or even if it is called, is uncertain. Therefore,
>   you **should not rely on this method** to do your cleanup for you. For
>   example, if you don't close file descriptors in your code after
>   performing I/O and you expect finalize() to close them for you, you
>   may run out of file descriptors.

Which begs the question: Are there any known **proper** uses of this method?

Comment: `finalize()` has been _deprecated_ since Java 9, by the way, just not for removal (in response to "_...it is still available, even in JDK 10_"). It might never be removed to ensure they don't break anything.

Comment: There is a thorough description in *Effective Java*. Google's internal practices page says of finalizers: 1) don't use them; 2) if you think you really need to use them, read the *Effective Java* item thoroughly. And then *still* don't use them. (There are cases where you do need them, e.g. interacting with native code. But the point is that you need them far, far less frequently than you might at first imagine).

Comment: @Slaw what does *"deprecated but might never be removed"* mean? :)

Comment: @WebViewer When an item shouldn't be used for some reason it can be marked as "deprecated". In Java, this is done with the [`Deprecated`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) annotation (Javadoc goes into more detail). However, just because an item has been deprecated doesn't mean it will be removed from the library. This is to ensure backwards compatibility; code compiled in Java 8 should run on Java 9. If backwards compatibility is not needed or desired then the item can be marked "deprecated for removal" which means it will be removed in a future version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "meta usage" might be the example status of this API: although it is known and recommended to not be used, it wasn't removed. Or even deprecated until Java 9.

You may look at this simple method as evidence that the people responsible for the Java language are super reluctant to break backwards compatibility. Even for methods nobody *should* be using!

So, the actual answer is: no, there isn't. Of course, you could use the method to make experiments under which conditions it gets invoked, but well, you can't rely on the results of that research.